# Связь между словами Волга и Болгары

Tags: этимология

Почему при обсуждении этимологии слов Волга и болгары никогда не упоминается почти очевидная связь Волга - волгари?

Comment: Отчего же никогда, упоминающих есть у нас: http://tat-etimology.livejournal.com/1805.html

Comment: Ну как минимум потому, что подобные гипотезы антиисторичны. Волга - из финских корней, булгары - из тюркских... Да и переход Б в В характерен для греческого и испанского. Но никак не для славянских, угорских и тюркских.

Comment: На всякий случай. Про финские корни - это я не совсем удачно выразился. финско-славянские, так скажем, что в данном контексте вполне можно противопоставить тюркским.

Comment: @behemothus, Фасмер указывает на славянское происхождение слова *Волга*. Какие известные этимологи усматривают в этом гидрониме финские корни?

Comment: @Пересвет назовите мне хоть одну причину, почему я должен отвечать на Ваш вопрос в такой форме. Все, что имеет отношение к теме, я сказал. Я противопоставляю финско-славянско-балтийские названия Волги тюркскому слову "булгар". С Фасмером в этом вопросе спорить не собираюсь. Не приписывайте мне подобное. подобное.  Остальное - в см. хотя бы в википедии в статье Волга.

Comment: @behemothus, в Википедии не указаны источники, из которых взяты версии о финском происхождении слова *Волга*, так что их можно опустить. Изначально Вы писали про финские корни, вот я и спросил, откуда дровишки. Пояснение появилось позже, и я его сначала не заметил.

Comment: Ну и до пояснений, и после совершенно непонятно, почему вы меня спрашиваете. Я эту тему "на защиту не выносил". Другое дело, что никак не могу понять, как "пояснение" которому на данный момент 4 полновесных часа, появится **после** вашего вопроса, которому - час от роду.

Answer (score 5):

Переспрошу: почему не упоминаются волгари в связи с Волгой?

Если пять авторитетных словарей не упоминание, тогда что же есть упоминание?

Макс Фасмер:

> Волга́рь - производное от Во́лга. Эту форму охотно привлекали для
>   толкования названия болгар, для чего исторические источники не дают
>   основания.

Владимир Даль:

> ВОЛГА́РЬ - коренной, прирожденный судовщик, ходок по Волге; бурлак.
>   Здесь народ волгарь; я, брат, и сам с Волги; народ тертый, плут; я и
>   сам наторел, знаю вашего брата.

Дмитрий Ушаков:

> ВОЛГА́РЬ (обл.).
>
> 1. Уроженец Поволжья.
> 2. Судовой рабочий в Поволжье.

Сергей Ожегов:

> ВОЛГА́РЬ. Уроженец Поволжья (обычно о работающем на реке).

Татьяна Ефремова:

> Волга́рь - уроженец или житель Поволжья.

А вот [**Большой толковый словарь русского языка**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C) утверждает, что "волгарь" - разговорное, а нормативное - "волжанин".

По поводу спорных болгар: верю Ефремовой.

> > Болга́ры
> >
> > 1. мн.
>
> 1) Народ южнославянской этноязыковой подгруппы, составляющий основное
>   население Болгарии.
>
> > 2) Представители этого народа.
> >
> > 2. мн.
>
> Тюркоязычные племена, обитавшие в Поволжье в средние века и создавшие
>   там государство в X—XIII вв.

[Уточнение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B) к болгарам/булгарам:

> Булга́ры, болга́ры (лат. Bulgares, греч. Βoύλγαρoί, болг. прабългари,
>   протобългари, тат. Bolğarlar, чуваш. Пӑлха́рсем, балк. Малкъар.) —
>   тюркские племена, населявшие с IV века степи Северного Причерноморья
>   до Каспия и Северного Кавказа и мигрировавшие во 2-й половине VII века
>   частично в Подунавье, а позднее в Среднее Поволжье и ряд других
>   регионов.
>
> **Участвовали в этногенезе** таких современных народов, как болгары, македонцы, татары, чуваши, башкиры, балкарцы, карачаевцы, и передали
>   своё имя государству Болгария. **В современной историографии
>   используются также термины протоболгары, праболгары, древние
>   болгары.**

Фасмеру этимология слова "болгарин" не представляется тёмной:

> Происходит от церк.-слав. блъгаринъ, болг. бъ́лгарин, сербохорв.
>   бу̏гарин, ср.-греч. βούλγαροι (уже Никиф. Григорас). Это название
>   являлось первонач. тюрк. племенным именем, др.-тюрк. bulɣar
>   «смешанного происхождения, метис» от bulɣamak «мешать». **Ошибочны были
>   попытки Шишманова и СбНУ объяснить это название от Во́лга.** Столь же
>   неудачна попытка Дечева рассматривать его как герм. название и,
>   предполагая исходное знач. «борец», сравнивать его с нем. balgen
>   «драться, бороться». От этого [тюрк.] народа произошло местн. н.
>   Болга́ры (на Волге, южнее Казани), араб. Bulgar, Burgar.

P. S. Для особо слабовидящих:  Фасмер, в котором не нахожу изъяна:

> **...Ошибочны были попытки Шишманова и СбНУ объяснить это название <болгары> от Во́лга.**

То есть **никакой связи** между гидронимом Волга и этнонимом болгарин.

Comment: Вывод, видимо, должен звучать так: ТО ЕСТЬ «при обсуждении этимологии слов Волга и болгары никогда не упоминается почти очевидная связь Волга - волгари», потому что эта связь на болгар не распространяется.